# Swift 3 Storyboard navigation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I have a login page that is built in a file called LoginViewController.swift

After the user logs in, I want to send them to a new storyboard that is built on TabBarController[image]

Item 2, which is the middle one is linked to a file called landingViewController.swift that contains:

```
import UIKit

class landingViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

In my LoginViewController, i want to navigate to that new storyboard in the API part of the function, i've made a comment area to show you.

```
//MARK: -API Request
func logintoUnicityLife(username:String , password:String){
    let params = ["username": username,
                  "password": password]

    print("login API called - \(params)")

    Alamofire.request(URL(string: "\(AppData.sharedData.APIUrl)/login")!,
                      method: .get,
                      parameters: params,
                      headers: AppData.sharedData.headerParam).validate().responseJSON(completionHandler: {(response) -> Void in
                        print("login API done - \(response.response?.statusCode)")

                        guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                            print("API fail: \(response.error.debugDescription)")
                            return
                        }
                        guard let value = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, Any>,
                            let result = value["result"] as? Dictionary<String, String> else {
                                print(response)
                                return
                        }

                        self.userDetails = result
                        print(self.userDetails)

                        // =========== NAVIGATE TO THE NEW STORYBOARD HERE =============

                        // =========== CODE GOES ABOVE HERE ==================

                      })
}
```

Comment: You need to load the New Storyboard on to the MainWindow, after logged in.

Comment: And how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func logintoUnicityLife(username:String , password:String){
        let params = ["username": username,
                      "password": password]

        print("login API called - \(params)")

        Alamofire.request(URL(string: "\(AppData.sharedData.APIUrl)/login")!,
                          method: .get,
                          parameters: params,
                          headers: AppData.sharedData.headerParam).validate().responseJSON(completionHandler: {(response) -> Void in
                            print("login API done - \(response.response?.statusCode)")

                            guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                                print("API fail: \(response.error.debugDescription)")
                                return
                            }
                            guard let value = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, Any>,
                                let result = value["result"] as? Dictionary<String, String> else {
                                    print(response)
                                    return
                            }

                            self.userDetails = result
                            print(self.userDetails)

                            // Tabbarcontrolloer set as initial ViewController
                            let tabVC = UIStoryboard(name:"<Your Storyboard file name>", bundle:nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
                            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController = tabVC

                            // =========== NAVIGATE TO THE NEW STORYBOARD HERE =============

                            // =========== CODE GOES ABOVE HERE ==================

                          })
    }
```

Comment: I think this partially works as I see the nagivation switch to a black screen. How can I fix this? What should I lookout for?

Answer (score 0):

1. set tab view controller in the second storyboard as initial view controller
2. After successful login , execute this code

   ```
   let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name:"second", bundle:nil) // second storyboard name is given as second
   let tabVC = storyBoard.instantiateInitialViewController()
   (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController = tabVC
   ```

OR

1. Set storyboard id to the tabview controller in the second storyboard
2. After successful login , execute this code

   ```
   let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name:"second", bundle:nil)// second storyboard name is given as second
   let tabVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabVc") // storyboard id of tab view controller is given as tabVc
   (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController = tabVC
   ```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a storyboard reference in your Login storyboard, create a Show segue between the LoginViewController and the storyboard reference, give it an identifier of "fromLoadingToMain", like so:

[image]

and then in your code, simply do :

```
// =========== NAVIGATE TO THE NEW STORYBOARD HERE =============
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "fromLoadingToMain", sender: nil)
// =========== CODE GOES ABOVE HERE ==================
```